# PyCharm не видит мой пакет

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

У меня есть свой пакет. Называется `app`. Он настроен при помощи `setup.py` и установлен в глобальный `Python` интерпретатор при помощи `pip install -e .` Отображается в `pip list`. Отображается в списке пакетов системного интерпретатора в настройках `PyCharm`.

В папке моего `PyCharm` проекта есть папки, которые называются так же, как и мой пакет. (В моём случае это папка в корне проекта и ещё одна папка внутри неё (обе называются `app`). Я работаю внутри этого пакета `app`, который импортирую.

Структура проекта:

```
project
   -app/
   -   -app/
   -   -   -views/
   -   -   -models/
   -   -   -__init__.py
   -   -setup.py
   -readme.md
   -...
```

В настройках `PyCharm` выбран системный интерпретатор.

Отображаются ошибки в импортах типа

```
import app.something
from app import something
```

Если, удерживая `Ctrl`, нажать на `app`, то PyCharm ссылает на корневую директорию `app`, хотя сам пакет по сути это внутренняя директория `app` (файл `setup.py` находится в первой папке `app` на уровне со второй (напомню, я работаю внутри этого пакета `app`, который импортирую))

Все эти импорты работают в `cmd`, но `PyCharm` предлагает следующие импорты

```
import app.app.something
from app.app import something
```

То есть импортировать из верхний `app` точка нижний `app` и из него обращаться к файлам проекта. Мне кажется это скорее относительный импорт(relative import) файлов, чем импорт библиотеки

Comment: Не хочется создавать лишние файлы. К тому же в этой папке уже есть файл `__init__.py` и это часть `flask` приложения

Answer (score 1):

`File > Settings > Project *Name* > Project structure` 
Выбрать первую *(верхнюю)* папку `app` и отметить её значком синей папочки 
`Mark as sources`

---

*Если не получается, попробуйте в настройках PyCharm вместо глобального интерпретатора настроить виртуальное окружение*